# ASP.NET -Masterpage vs frame/frameset

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET -Masterpage or frame/frameset. Which one is good in terms of performance and handling sessions.

Comment: you have confuze what the masterpage is. Take some time to make some examples of it. And avoid frames...

Comment: No. I have no confusion over masterPage. Masterpage makes sometimes  unnecessary round-trips and that slows page to load.

Comment: No, masterpage after the compile is not make any roud-trips. The page after the compile is load super fast in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Never never use frame/frameset. They [are](http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil) evil.

Answer (score 0):

Frames have been obsolete since at least 1997.

see: http://staff.washington.edu/rells/topics/frames.html

I actually had a problem today with them and our extremely old codebase. It took me ~10 hours to pull something from the query string that should have taken a single line of

```
request.querystring()
```

but since there are about 5 different frames on the page and it was being accessed by URL, I couldn't actually get the QueryString from the frame that I wanted.